# How to make codnitive sidenav slide up/down?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slide

I have the magneto extension "Codnitive Sidenav" but in order to make it slideUp/Down 
some extra coding is needed.

the original navigation.phtml code for sidenav is:

```
    <?php if ($categories = $this->getCategoriesNavMenu()): ?>
    <div id="sidebar-nav" class="block sidebar-nav-left <?php echo $this-     >getBlockAlias() ?>">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($this->getTitle()) ?></span></strong> 
</div>
<div class="block-content">
    <ul id="sidebar-nav-menu">
    <?php if ($this->showHome()): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $this->getHomeClasses() ?>">
            <a title="Go to Home Page" href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>"><span class="category_name"></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $categories; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php if ($this->showSupportLogo()): ?>
    <div class="clearer support-logo-wrapper"></div>
    <a href="http://www.codnitive.com/" target="_blank" class="support_logo">
        <?php if ($this->showAsImage()): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/codnitive/sidenav/codnitive_logo.png'); ?>" alt="CODNITIVE&reg;" title="Sidebar Navigation by CODNITIVE"/>
        <?php else: ?>
        <span>CODNITIVE&REG;</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php if ($this->getConfig()->isCollapsible()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[

Codnitive = {
    expandMenu: function(parent) 
    {
        var mode = parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getAttribute("expanded");
        (mode == 1) ? Codnitive.collapse(parent) : Codnitive.expand(parent);
    },

    expand: function(parent)
    {
        parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "block";
        parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.backgroundPosition = "right center";
        parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].setAttribute("expanded", "1");
    },

    collapse: function(parent)
    {
        parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none";
        parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.backgroundPosition = "left center";
        parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].setAttribute("expanded", "0");
    }
};

//]]>
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the original code for navigation.php is:

```
    <?php



 */
public function getConfig()
{
    if ($this->_config === null) {
        $this->_config = Mage::getModel('sidenav/config');
    }

    return $this->_config;
}

/**
 * Get store categories navigation menu
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCategoriesNavMenu()
{
    $navigationMenu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0);
    return $navigationMenu ? $navigationMenu : false;
}

/**
 * We set cache to null when product direct access option is enabled and customer
 * is in product page to avoid wrong category tree showing with enabled caches
 * 
 * Adds 1 extra second to page load
 * Ultra version has caching and best performance
 * 
 * @return null
 */
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    $condition = (Mage::registry('current_product') !== null) 
            && ($this->getConfig()->activeProductCategoriesInDirectAccess());
    if ($condition) {
        return null;
    }

    return parent::getCacheLifetime();
}

/**
 * Get catagories of current store
 *
 * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
 */
public function getStoreCategories()
{
    return Mage::helper('sidenav/category')->getStoreCategories();
}

/**
 * Returns category model
 * 
 * @return Codnitive_Sidenav_Model_Category
 */
protected function _getCategoryModel()
{
    return Mage::getModel('sidenav/catalog_category');
}

/**
 * Retruns data helper
 * 
 * @return Codnitive_Sidenav_Helper_Data
 */
protected function _getHelper()
{
    return Mage::helper('sidenav');
}

/**
 * Render category to html
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
 * @param int Nesting level number
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is first, affects list item class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is outermost, affects list item class
 * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
 * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
 * @param boolean Whether ot not to add on* attributes to list item
 * @return string
 */
protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
        $category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, 
        $isFirst = false, $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', 
        $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false
) {
    if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        return '';
    }

    $config = $this->getConfig();
    $html = array();
    $expanded = null;
    $ulThumb = '';
    $image = '';
    $thumb = '';
    $htmlLi = '';

    // get all children
    if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
        $children = (array) $category->getChildrenNodes();
        $childrenCount = count($children);
    }
    else {
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        if (!$this->_getHelper()->isSearchResultsPage()) {
            $childrenCount = $children->count();
        }
        else {
            if (is_string($children)) {
                $children = explode(',', $children);
            }
            $childrenCount = count($children);
        }
    }

    // select active children
    $activeChildren = array();
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeChildren[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
    $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

    // prepare list item html classes
    $classes = array();
    $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
    $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
    if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    else if ((Mage::registry('current_product') !== null) && ($config->activeProductCategoriesInDirectAccess())) {
        $classes = $this->_getCategoryModel()->getProductCategoriesInDirectAccess($category, $classes);
    }

    $linkClass = '';
    if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
        $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
        $linkClass = ' class="' . $outermostItemClass . '"';
    }
    if ($isFirst) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }
    if ($isLast) {
        $classes[] = 'last';
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren) {
        $classes[] = 'parent';
    }

    // prepare list item attributes
    $attributes = array();
    if (count($classes) > 0) {
        $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
        $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
        $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
    }

    // assemble list item with attributes
    $thumbWidth = 14;
    $thumbHeight = 14;
    $thumbPosition = $config->getThumbPosition();
    $liMarginLeft = 0;
    $ulMarginLeft = 5;
    $ulPaddingLeft = 10;

    // define image thumbnail variables
    if ($config->isThumbImageActive()) {
        if ($config->getThumbSize()) {
            $thumbWidth = $config->getThumbWidth();
            $thumbHeight = $config->getThumbHeight();
        }
        $thumbnail = $this->_getCategoryModel()->load($category->getId())->getThumbnailImageUrl();
        $ulThumb = ' ul-thumb';
        if (!empty($thumbnail)) {
            $image = '<img class="thumb-img-' . $thumbPosition . '" src="' . $thumbnail . '" style= "width:' . $thumbWidth . 'px; height:' . $thumbHeight . 'px; float: ' . $thumbPosition . ';" />';
            $thumb = ' thumb';

            if ($thumbPosition === 'left') {
                if ($config->isCollapsible() && $config->isThumbImageActive()) {
                    $liMarginLeft = $thumbWidth + 3;
                    $ulMarginLeft = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $liMarginLeft = 0;
                    $ulMarginLeft = $thumbWidth + 3;
                }
                $ulPaddingLeft = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            $thumb = ' no-thumb';
            $liMarginLeft = ($thumbPosition === 'right') ? 0 : $thumbWidth + 3;
            if ($thumbPosition === 'left') {
                $ulMarginLeft = 0;
                $ulPaddingLeft = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    $collapsibleClass = '';
    if ($config->isCollapsible()) {
        $collapsibleClass = ' collapsible';
    }

    // add collapsible arrow and wrraper
    $arrow = '';
    $extraStyle = '';
    $collapsibleIconPosition = $config->getCollapsibleIconPosition();
    if ($config->isCollapsible()) {
        $width = $config->getCollapsibleIconType() === 'arrow' ? 8 : 16;
        $height = 0;
        $expanded = 0;
        if ($hasActiveChildren) {
            $width = $config->getCollapsibleIconType() === 'arrow' ? 8 : 16;
            $height = 16;
        }
        if ($height == 0) {
            $extraStyle = ' display:none;';
        }
        if ($height == 0 && $collapsibleIconPosition === 'left') {
            $liMarginLeft += $width;
        }
        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $expanded = 1;
        }
        $expanded = ' expanded="' . $expanded .'"';
        $spanOnclick = 'onclick="Codnitive.expandMenu(this.parentNode)';
        $spanClass   = $config->getCollapsibleIconType() . '-' . $collapsibleIconPosition;
        $arrow = '<span class="' . $spanClass . ' " ' . $spanOnclick . '" style="width: ' . $width . 'px; height: ' . $height . 'px;' . $extraStyle . '"></span>';
    }

    $htmlLi .= '<li';
    foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
        $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . $thumb . $collapsibleClass . '"';
    }

    $htmlLi .= ' style="margin-left: ' . $liMarginLeft . 'px;' . '">';
    $html[] = $htmlLi;

    $html[] = $arrow;

    // add wrapper
    $aClass  = '';
    $aStyle  = '';
    $onclick = '';
    if ($config->isCollapsible() || $config->isThumbImageActive()) {
        $wrapperMargin = ($config->isCollapsible() && $collapsibleIconPosition === 'left') ? 14 : 0;
        $extraMargin = !$config->isThumbImageActive() ? 0 : (!empty($thumbnail) && ($thumbPosition === 'left')) ? $thumbWidth + 3 : 0;
        $collWrapper = $wrapperMargin + $extraMargin;

        // makes parent category name clickable to open/close collapsible menus if option is enabled
        $collapseName = '';
        if ($hasActiveChildren && $config->isCollapsible() && $config->expandByParentName()) {
            $onclick = ' onclick="Codnitive.expandMenu(this.parentNode);return false;"';
            $collapseName = ' collapse-name';
        }
        $aClass = 'class="collapsible-wrapper' . $collapseName . '"';
        $aStyle = ' style="margin-left: ' . $collWrapper . 'px;"';
    }

    $html[] = '<a ' . $aClass . $onclick . 'href="' . $this->getCategoryUrl($category) . '"'
            . $linkClass .'>' . '<span class="category_name">'
            . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span></a>';

    // add thumbnail image
    $html[] = $image;

    // add product count
    if ($config->showProductCount()) {
        $count = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')
                ->setCurrentCategory($category->getID())
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->getSize();
        if (($config->removeZeroCount() && $count > 0) || !$config->removeZeroCount()) {
            $html[] = '<span class="product-count">(' . $count . ')</span>';
        }
    }

    // render children
    $htmlChildren = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
        $htmlChildren .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $child, ($level + 1), ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1), ($j == 0), false, $outermostItemClass, $childrenWrapClass, $noEventAttributes
        );
        $j++;
    }
    if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
        }
        $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . $ulThumb . $collapsibleClass .
                '" style="margin-left: ' . $ulMarginLeft .
                'px; padding-left: ' . $ulPaddingLeft . 'px;"' . $expanded . '>';
        $html[] = $htmlChildren;
        $html[] = '</ul>';
        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '</div>';
        }
    }

    $html[] = '</li>';

    $html = implode("\n", $html);
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Render categories menu in HTML
 *
 * @param int Level number for list item class to start from
 * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
 * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
 * @return string
 */
public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
{
    $currentId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $currentLevel = $this->_getCategoryModel()->load($currentId)->getLevel();
    if ($registerdCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
        $currentId    = $registerdCategory->getId();
        $currentLevel = $registerdCategory->getLevel();
    }

    $config     = $this->getConfig();
    $paretnType = $config->getParent();
    $categories = $this->getStoreCategories();

    $activeCategories = array();
    foreach ($categories as $child) {
        // this condition use for "Current Category and Children" option
        $condition = ($paretnType == 'current') 
                && ($child->getLevel() == $currentLevel) 
                && ($child->getId() != $currentId);
        if ($child->getIsActive() && !$condition) {
            $activeCategories[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeCategoriesCount = count($activeCategories);
    $hasActiveCategoriesCount = ($activeCategoriesCount > 0);

    if (!$hasActiveCategoriesCount) {
        return '';
    }

    $html = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeCategories as $category) {
        $html .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $category, $level, ($j == $activeCategoriesCount - 1), 
                ($j == 0), true, $outermostItemClass, $childrenWrapClass, true
        );
        $j++;
    }

    return $html;
}

/**
 * Get category title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    $title = '';
    $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

    switch ($this->getConfig()->getTitleType()) {
        case 'current':
            if ($currentCategory) {
                $title = $currentCategory->getName();
            }
            break;

        case 'parent':
            if ($currentCategory) {
                $parent = $currentCategory->getParentCategory();
                $rootId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
                if ($parent->getId() != $rootId) {
                    $title = $parent->getName();
                }
            }
            break;

        case 'static':
            $title = $this->getConfig()->getStaticTitle();
    }

    if (!$title) {
        $title = $this->getConfig()->getStaticTitle();
    }

    return $title;
}

/**
 * Retrieves home page link must show
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public function showHome()
{
    if ($this->_getHelper()->isHome() && $this->getConfig()->removeHomeInHome()) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->getConfig()->showHome();
}

/**
 * Returns all classes for home link
 * 
 * @return string
 */
public function getHomeClasses()
{
    $classes = 'level0 nav-0 parent home';

    if ($this->getConfig()->isCollapsible()) {
        $classes .= ' collapsible';
    }

    if ($this->_getHelper()->isHome()) {
        $classes .= ' active';
    }

    return $classes;
}

/**
 * Retrieves which CODNITIVE logo must show or not
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public function showSupportLogo()
{
    return $this->getConfig()->showSupportLogo();
}

/**
 * Retrieves which CODNITIVE logo must show as image or text
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public function showAsImage()
{
    return $this->getConfig()->showAsImage();
}

/**
 * Get extension enable status
 *
 * @deprecated after 1.7.20
 *     We don't need to check for module activation option
 *     in template, we check it in layout.
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isActive()
{
    return $this->getConfig()->isActive();
}

/**
 * Get selected column
 *
 * @deprecated after 1.7.20
 *     We don't need to check for selected column option
 *     in template, we check it in layout.
 * 
 * @return string
 */
public function getColumn()
{
    return $this->getConfig()->getColumn();
}
```

}

I was told to replace the javascript code in navigation.phtml with the code here below:

```
    (function($) {
    Codnitive = {

    sideMenu: 
    {
        expandMenu: function($parent)
        {
            var $ul = $parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
            var $span = $parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
            ($ul.getAttribute("expanded") == 1)
                    ? Codnitive.sideMenu.collapse($ul, $span)
                    : Codnitive.sideMenu.expand($ul, $span);
        },
        expand: function($ul, $span)
        {
            $($ul).slideDown(300, function() {
                $ul.setAttribute("expanded", "1");
                $span.style.backgroundPosition = "right center";
            });
        },
        collapse: function($ul, $span)
        {
            $($ul).slideUp(400, function() {
                $ul.setAttribute("expanded", "0");
                $span.style.backgroundPosition = "left center";
            });
        }
    },

})(jQuery);
```

AND call it like this:

```
    onclick="Codnitive.sideMenu.expandMenu(this.parentNode)"
```

so I tried this, like so:

```
    $expanded = ' expanded="' . $expanded .'"';
        $spanOnclick = 'onclick="Codnitive.expandMenu(this.parentNode)';
        $spanClass   = $config->getCollapsibleIconType() . '-' .    $collapsibleIconPosition;
        $arrow = '<span class="' . $spanClass . ' " ' . $spanOnclick . '" style="width: ' . $width . 'px; height: ' . $height . 'px;' . $extraStyle . '"></span>';
```

and

```
    if ($hasActiveChildren && $config->isCollapsible() && $config->expandByParentName()) {
            $onclick = ' onclick="Codnitive.sideMenu.expandMenu(this.parentNode);return      false;"';
```

But it didn't work so my question is: What am I doing wrong here?
does it have to do with the misplacement of " "?

Does anyone know what I should do to make this work?

much obliged,

Tuutuutuut

Comment: What exactly doesn't work and what's the JavaScript error you get?

Comment: well it just won't respond anymore  (no expand nor close)

the error is


uncaught syntaxerror:expected token ')'

Comment: and when I click on sidenav item or arrow I get

Uncaught ReferenceError: Codnitive is not defined
              onclick